# Format the value of data point in overview page card header

Tags: formatting, sapui5, sap-fiori

A service returns `0.05` to indicate `5%`. Is there any UI annotation to format this value so that the card header will show `5%` ?
The `datapoint` has the `ValueFormat` but that doesn't really solve my issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Just use the formatter/expression binding to format the value as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a formatter function like this:

```
function formatPercent(nPercentage) {
    return (nPercentage*100).toString() + '%'; 
}

// Input 0.05
// Output '5%'
```

(Add type checks, truncating, etc)